# Internal Beta testing App showing warning message on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, warnings

We had released a new beta version of the android application and the app is now currently being tested using Google Play. I am one of the beta tester and found a warning message being shown for this app as "**You're and internal tester. This app may be unsecure or unstable**" in the Google Play Store.

Can you please let me know what is causing this issue ? and the steps that need to be followed in order to fix the issue?

-A.K.Srinivas

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue, any time you are a tester, you will see this message on the Play Store. This is merely to let the users know that hence this is a version which is not GA (General Availability) it may crash, or cause bad experience, since that's the reason why we generally test.

You can't do anything to change this, it's the intended behaviour for testers.

Answer (score 0):

You might have joined the internal testing program as well for this. You should click that and click "Leave Programme" and then you will be ablle to see the Public Version and this message may not appear then.